# regex address extraction

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having the most difficult time with getting this right.

I have the following HTML that I'm trying to parse the address "     100 E Faith Ter" out of

```
    <span style="border-color: rgb(0, 0, 255); border-width: 2px; border-style: solid;"                 class="addr">     100 E Faith Ter<br>            <span class="locality">Maitland</span>,                     <span class="region">FL</span>            <span class="postal-code">32751</span>                    </span>l-code">32751</span>            </span>
```

I"m trying to pass in this html above to this set of code and I'm getting no match and I don't understand why even though I try it in regex testers and it works.  I'm going insane.

```
    function demoShowMatchClick(addressToPull) {
      var re = new RegExp("\s{5}(.*?<br>)");
      var m = re.exec(addressToPull);
      if (m == null) {
        alert("No match");
      } else {
        var s = "Match at position " + m.index + ":\n";
        for (i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
          s = s + m[i] + "\n";
        }
        alert(s);
      }
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: See my answer, however, I'm not sure it's such a good idea to be matching on a specific amount of white-space.

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex, are we?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var re = new RegExp("\\s{5}(.*?<br>)");
```

Escaping the \s

If you use the literal regexp syntax, you don't have to worry about string escaping:

```
var re = /\s{5}(.*?<br>)/
```

Comment: Thanks.  That worked except now for some reason I'm getting double the address like this from this function.  100 E Faith Ter<br>,100 E Faith Ter<br>

       function demoShowMatchClick(addressToPull) {
         var re = /\s{5}(.*?<br>)/;
         var m = re.exec(addressToPull);
         return m;

Answer (score 0):

```
you have to make following changes in your function

 function demoShowMatchClick(addressToPull) {
      var re = \s{5}(.*?<br>);
      var m = re.exec(addressToPull);
      if (re.test(addressToPull)) {
        var s = "Match at position " + m.index + ":\n";
        for (i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
          s = s + m[i] + "\n";
            alert(s);
      } else {

             alert("No match");
        }

      }
    }
```